# MAUI: How to update an observable property and wait for UI update completion before updating it again?

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I have this problem in my code that when I write CurrentCanvas = null, and then initialize CurrentCanvas = ... then my UI doesn't have time to update this bindings, so I used some kind of kludge Task.Delay(10) to wait for the UI to update (although basically what I'm doing is also a kind of kludge, but not as bad as this), but I'd like to get rid of it, because using delays can be detrimental to the application, is there any way or workaround in my situation (this is the code from ViewModel)

```
[RelayCommand]
private async Task SelectCanvasAsync(ObservableCanvas selectedCanvas)
{
    if (CurrentCanvas == selectedCanvas)
    {
        CurrentCanvas = null;
        IsCanvasNull = true;
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentCanvas = null;
        await Task.Delay(20); // KLUDGE!!!!! // UI Updates in milliseconds
        CurrentCanvas = selectedCanvas;
        IsCanvasNull = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do and why. Why do you need to set `CurrentCanvas` to `null` before assigning `selectedCanvas` to it? Why don't you assign`selectedCanvas` directly to it? It would be helpful to give more context.

Comment: Unsure of your specifics, but you might try `await Task.Yield()`. That will force the remaining lines in that branch to execute only after all other *synchronous* code in the current dispatcher loop has finished. That *usually* means the UI logic will have updated all properties and bindings (though possibly not rendered, but that's not necessarily a dealbreaker) by the time it gets back to you. If that *doesn't* work, then that means you're dependent on something asynchronous, which in turn means your `Task.Delay` probably won't work 100% of the time, and you'd best rethink things.

Comment: Alternatively, the best approach in these kinds of situations, I've found, is to figure a way to get some kind of one-time callback when the thing you're waiting for is ready to do whatever it is you want it to do, and use that in conjunction with a `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your feedback. 
Let me be clear why am i doing this. I am working on a diagram editor (currently implementing it as an image editor) and I tried to create a custom ScrollView that scrolls to saved positions in the canvas when selected, at first I tried to do this through PropertyChanged, but PropertyChanged code worked faster than the UI was ready, so I decided to implement it a little differently.

Comment: I made a flag IsScrollReady and marked it as true in PropertyChanged, and I bound the SizeChanged event to the BoxView (my canvas that appears through the CurrentCanvas binding from the ViewModel), everything worked fine, but as soon as I started creating canvases of the same size, this event did not trigger.

Comment: So I decided to make a this thingy with CurrentCanvas = null, so that ScrollView would clear first, and then initialize with a new canvas, this way everything worked great, but due to the fact that the UI does not update instantly after changing CurrentCanvas to null, I had to put a delay, which I would like to get rid of and look for more elegant ways. I won't argue, my way is also far from the most elegant, but it's the best I could come up with at the moment.

Comment: You should add useful information to the question. Elaborate on the problem, not just the symptoms, that you're ***actually*** trying to solve and show the relevant code, not just bits that don't provide any useful context. What is the purpose the the `SelectCanvasCommand`? Why would a user call this?

Comment: Ahh ok, my bad. There is a collection view that represents a bar of buttons each of which changes CurrentCanvas. So in user case, if the user wants to change canvas to another one, he presses one of these buttons and calls SelectCanvasCommand